# JavaScript PDF Email not prompt

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have an issue with this coding

```
var x =this.getField("Signature2").value
if(x == ""){app.alert("please ensure all the required fields is filled-in before sending", 3);
}
else{

this.submitForm = "email@gmail.com"; 

var cSubLine = "Request Form - " + this.getField("Account").value + this.getField("Account number").value +", " + this.getField("COMPANY NAME").value;
var cBody = "Details for Request-" + this.getField("Account").value + this.getField("Account number").value +"," + this.getField("COMPANY NAME").value + ", " + this.getField("COMPANY NAME").value +" , "+ this.getField("COMPANY NAME").value;  

  this.mailDoc({  
  bUI: true,  
  cTo: cToAddr,  
  cSubject: cSubLine,  
  cMsg: cBody  
});    
}
```

1. So when the field named signature is not filled in there is a pop-up warning box to inform the user to fill in the empty field.
2. However, the box that prompt email won't appear even after the user filled in all the fields.
3. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: help anyone....?

Comment: Hi so sorry really need help in this. Can anyone help me?